Calculate MPS tensor for a given translationally invariant state (numerically)
Assume you are given a many-body state that lives on a 1D chain with local Hilbertspace dimension $d$ on each site and length $N$ as a vector $|\psi \rangle\in \mathbb{C}^{d^N}$. Let the state be translationally invariant with periodic boundary conditions (PBC), i.e.
\begin{align}
|\psi \rangle=\sum_{\{s\}}a_{s_1s_2\ldots s_N} |s_1 s_2\ldots s_N\rangle
\end{align}
where the tensor $a$ is translationally invariant with periodic boundary contions $a_{s_1s_2,\ldots s_N} = a_{s_N s_1s_2\ldots s_{N-1}}$.
I want to (numerically) compute a tensor $B\in \mathbb{C}^{d\times D\times D}$ of bond dimension $D$ that approximates $|\psi\rangle$ as an MPS and takes the translation invariance into account
\begin{align}
|\psi \rangle \approx|\psi_B\rangle = \sum_{\{s\}} \text{tr}\left(B^{(s_1)}B^{(s_2)}\ldots B^{(s_N)}\right) | s_1 s_2 \ldots s_N \rangle
\end{align}
Note that the tensor $B$ is the same for every physical site, reflecting the translational symmetry.
I know that in general, one can approximate a state via recursive SVDs on $a$. This is somtimes called a tensortrain-SVD and returns a tensor that differs for different sites of the chain: it is not translationally invariant even if the input tensor is.
Is there a method or an algorithm that yields such a tensor $B$?
In particular I am interested in comparing the result with MPS formulations of states like the AKLT ground state under PBC. This specific example is translationally invariant and can be written exactly with bond dimension $D=2$. I know that in general the higher $D$, the better the approximation of the state. So I would expect an algorithm that truncates the local ranks at $D=2$ to only yield a tensor that approximate the given input state. Is there a way reproduce an exact $D=2$ MPS formulation by means of an algorithmic recipe?

Clarification: Is the state translationally invariant with period $N$ or with respect to an arbitrary translation (or equivalently with period 1)?

It is translationally invariant with respect to any translation, so yes period 1.

I don't understand the second question -- the one in the last paragraph. For the first part of the question, you could use e.g. a gradient-based method. (And then, the method -- if it converges -- should return the AKLT state, so it will give the correct D=2 formulation)

If I understand your question correctly you might be looking for something like periodic DMRG.
